# Is there supersymmetry between Dirac and Klein Gordon solutions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, dirac-equation, klein-gordon-equation

Usually supersymmetry is explained at the level of the action of a quantum field theory, and there are two ways to go down from QFT to *relativistic* quantum mechanics: either a non-covariant way where QM is simply a 0+1 dimensional theory, or an one-particle projection where we only look at the states that we can generate with only one particle creation operator. I am interested on how SUSY looks in this second approach:

- Is it possible to go from field excitations to traditional solutions of spin zero and spin 1/2 equations? I have seen that Weinberg does it for spin 1/2 in an external field, at the end of vol I, and I guess that it can be also done for spin zero. Ok, this is a question on itself, but took it as a preliminary issue.
- If it is, then are the solutions of Klein-Gordon and Dirac related in some way via the supersymmetry transformation? How?
- Particularly, is it possible to show in the KG wavefunction that a iteration of the susy transformation amounts to a translation?

Comment: Possible references http://www.iaea.org/inis/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/28/002/28002527.pdf http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370269382906116 https://inspirehep.net/record/109550?ln=es

Comment: More possible references: http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.2543, http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.0733, P. Di Vecchia and V. Schuchhardt, “N = 1 and N = 2 Supersymmetric Positronium”, Phys. Lett. B155, 427 (1985), W. Buchmu ̈ller, S. T. Love and R. D. Peccei, “Supersymmetric Bound States”, Nucl. Phys. B204, 429 (1982).  Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: @user2309840 I was thinking on something coming from QFT, and preferentially 3+1 QFT. Relativistic QM looks an acceptable answer if nobody is going to try to explain via 3+1 one-particle states, but it should still explain how the transform KG--->Dirac--->KG becomes a translation. Note that articles on "Susy QM" are usually about a different subject, pairs of potentials without really considering Spin or spacial translations.

Comment: So how about (2.26) and (2.34) in arxiv.org/abs/0912.2543?  In the non-relativistic limit for massive particles of mass $m$, the wave-function should have the dependence $e^{i m t}$ in both the fermionic and bosonic case. Acting twice with the SUSY generator should be like acting with $\partial_t$, which brings down a factor of $m$.

Comment: Only referring to the title of your question (in not the details), the Dirac-equation actually describes 2 particles, namely $e_L$ and $e_R$, coupled in a special way whereas a single KG-equation describes only one particle. So SUSY  can only exist between 1 KG-particle and 1 Majorama-particle, Dirac represents a 2 (especially coupled) Majorama particles.